# How minify an Angular Prj

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, ng-html2js

This is my problem ...

I prepare the next small exmaple, with the gruntFile.js 
and i can get minify this

this is the error that i have:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.11/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp
```

this is the link to see my example:

https://github.com/juliovg/minification_Test.git

**can somebody help me?**

Thanks

Comment: this will make no difference, but please remove one ng-app="myApp" from your html..It has declared twice

Answer (score 1):

1st thing remove one `ng-app="myApp"` directive to initialize, because it has declared you twice.
You must follow array annotation of dependency injection to ensure the correct minification without error, you missed it inside directive.

**Directive**

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('beerFormDirective',[ function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        templateUrl: 'js/directives/beerForm/beerForm_view.html',
        scope: {},
        controller: 'beerForm_controller' //added controller from view
    };
}]);
```

and remove `ng-controller` from your html template.
& for better performance do load javascript file from local rather than from cdn